# Joining tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a master data table like this:

```
tableA 
 ID | tainfo1 | tainfo2
 ----------------------
  1 | me      | 100
  2 | you     | 200
  3 | they    | 300
```

and an attribute table like that:

```
tableB:
 ID | type  | tbinfo1 | tbinfo2
 ------------------------------
 1  | 1     | good    | 7
 1  | 2     | bad     | 5
 2  | 2     | so&so   | 6
 3  | 1     | awesome | 10
```

In the attribute table i have a very small set of `type` and I would like to know if there's any chance to make data output like this.

```
 ID | tainfo1 | tainfo2 | tbinfo1_type1 | tbinfo2_type1 | tbinfo1_type2 | tbinfo2_type2 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | me      | 100     | good          | 7             | bad           | 5
 2  | you     | 200     |               |               | so&so         | 6
 3  | they    | 300     | awesome       | 10            |               |
```

if all the attributes exists, all the columns are filled, like the record 1, also the `_typeX` column will appear blanks, like the record 2 for type1

I hope the question is clear,
Regards.

Comment: select ... from tableA ta join tableb tb1 join tableb tb2...

Comment: You want to transpose result set from rows to columns with dynamic columns count. I think that it is not possible to do in pure SQL. If you know the maximum number of related rows in TableB then you could do multiple joins as jarlh said earlier.

Comment: is the number of types dynamic or constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join both tables and [pivot](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE) result:

```
select * 
  from (
    select id, tainfo1, tainfo2, type, tbinfo1, tbinfo2 
      from tableA join tableB using (id))
  pivot (max(tbinfo1) t1, max(tbinfo2) t2 for type in (1 info1, 2 info2))
```

Output:

```
   ID TAINFO1       TAINFO2 INFO1_T1     INFO1_T2 INFO2_T1     INFO2_T2
----- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    1 me                100 good                7 bad                 5 
    2 you               200                       so-so               6 
    3 they              300 awesome            10
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/473af/1)

This will work for defined number of values in column `type`. Also `pivot` is available from Oracle 11g version, for older versions use `max(decode...)` like [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php). If you need fully dynamical solution then please read articles: [link1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42asktom-1653097.html), [link2](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/).